# Laravel Functions & their usage

Tags: laravel

**The following code is to add a task to the ToDo list.**

- What does the Laravel Function ->withInput()  & ->withErrors($validator) mean?
- Does the withError() has anything to do with common.errors? If so how?

  ```
  Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['name' => 'required|max:255',]);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect('/')
          ->withInput()
          ->withErrors($validator);
  }

  $task = new Task;
  $task->name = $request->name;
  $task->save();

  return redirect('/');
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withInput()` meant for flashing your input to your session,so you can use it in the views like after validation fails you can display in the input box what you entered in the form before you submit.So you don't have to enter again.

For details check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input

`withError()` is the method to flash the error messages to the session and you can display those errors in your view.

Check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators

These two functions is used when you manually create validations

You can also validate the form without these functions using

```
$request->validate([
'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
'name' => 'required',
'description' => 'required',
]);
```